# Ember.js: How are Views connected to Controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

```
this.get('controller')
```

is coming up null.

I am wondering if someone can explain how ember views are associated with ember controllers.  Thank you.

Comment: view are associated either by naming convention lookup or manually

Comment: would you mind elaborating on that or giving me a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow ember's naming conventions, then for example the View `InfoView` would be hooked up automatically with `InfoController` by ember.

```
App.InfoView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'info'
});

App.InfoController = Ember.Controller.extend({});
```

so if you later do `this.get('controller')` in your View you should get the controller.

see this fiddle for an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AywvW/20/

Comment: you could do this in the route's setupController mehtod

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working.  Simply added this line to the view:

```
controllerBinding: "App.myController",
```